# How to limit a model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Well I have a model call Group.

I want add a validation that prevents more than 8 groups

Help me please

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :presence => true
    validates :name, :uniqueness => true
    validates :name, :length => { :is => 1 }
    validates :name, :format => { :with => /\A[A-Z]+\z/, :message => "Grupo Invalido" }
end
```

Comment: Hmm, do you want to limit the amount of registries under a particular scope? Or just overall prevent the creation of more than 8 groups?

Comment: yes, prevent the creation of more than 8 groups. Its an aplication for  world cup, thats why I need only 8 groups

Comment: But if thats the case, you'd create the 8 groups directly on the database and not have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, :presence => true
    validates :name, :uniqueness => true
    validates :name, :length => { :is => 1 }
    validates :name, :format => { :with => /\A[A-Z]+\z/, :message => "Grupo Invalido" }
    validate :max_count, on: :create

    def max_count
      errors.add(:base, 'Max group count limit reached') if Group.count >= 8
    end
end
```